# Rails server tells me--- couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/datepicker' with type 'application/javascript'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

```
couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/datepicker' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths: 
  /Users/jsbae/Desktop/unisports/app/assets/config
  /Users/jsbae/Desktop/unisports/app/assets/images
  /Users/jsbae/Desktop/unisports/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/jsbae/Desktop/unisports/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/jsbae/Desktop/unisports/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/jsbae/Desktop/unisports/vendor/assets/stylesheets
```

This is what is happening when I try to run the rails server. I have checked my gem list and can see I have:

```
jquery-rails (4.2.2, 4.2.1)
jquery-turbolinks (2.1.0)
jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1, 5.0.5)
jqueryui_rails (0.0.4)
```

I have seen a lot of posts on problems with the versions, so I also tried to downgrade jquery-rails and jquery-ui-rails, but when running the commands such as:

```
gem install 'jquery-rails','~>2.3.0' OR gem install 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
```

But they constantly send me errors like:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'jquery-rails-2.3.0' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: jquery_rails3, jquery-rails, jquery-rails-cdn, jquery-rails_vho, jquery-rails-aristo
```

I have also tried editing the application.js and application.css files with
`*= require jquery-ui' & '//= require jquery-ui`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `jquery-rails` or `jquery-ui-rails` in the Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
# gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to solve your problem is:

1. Download `jquery-ui` from http://jqueryui.com/download/
2. Exact and copy `jquery-ui.min.js` to `app/assets/javascripts/` and `jquery-ui.min.css` to `app/assets/stylesheets/`
3. In `application.js` and `application.css`, make sure that you have this line:

   `//= require_tree .` and `*= require_tree .`